# Is it possible to specify schema_name during instantiation?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using `Spring 2.5.5` and `Hibernate 3.2.1`.

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "mailing", name = "mailing")
public class Mailing {
    //Fields, GET, SET
}
```

The issue is I need to use that entity in more than one project and in some of those projects we should specify defferent `schema_name`. I'd like to put this entity class in the common place in order to avoid code-duplicating. For instance in the `Project A` schema name is `commmon_maling`, but in `Project B` schema name is just `mailing`. Is it possible to specify the schema name in the `springApplicationContext.xml` where we're defining the `SessionFactory` bean like the following:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                 <!-- Some classes -->
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the `hibernateProperties` property and add schema inside, e.g.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                 <!-- Some classes -->
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
               ...
               <property name="hibernate.default_schema">yourschema</property>
               ...
            </props>            
        </property>
</bean>
```